# Dice Simulator project in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dice

My code works to quit the program for my 'elif' and 'else' statements, but when I input 'yes', I'm stuck in this input loop where anything I input still rolls the dice. How can I get out of the program by inputting 'no', once I've already inputted 'yes' and entered the loop?

---

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

prompt = "Roll dice? Type yes or no. "
roll_dice = input(prompt)

while roll_dice:

    if roll_dice == "yes":
        print ("you rolled", random.randint(min, max), random.randint(min, max))
        input(prompt)

    elif roll_dice == "no":
        print ("see you later!")
        break

    else:
        print ("invalid answer")
        break
```

Comment: You need to update the value of roll_dice just like the first time. `roll_dice = input(prompt)`

Comment: `roll_dice = input(prompt)` inside `if roll_dice == "yes":`

Comment: Please don't edit the code in your question to be the fixed version, rather than the non-working version that you were asking about. Asking "why doesn't this code work" and then showing working code just confuses everybody. We want to preserve the original mistakes so that the answers below will be useful to other people having similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just doing:

```
input(prompt)
```

Which does nothing with the given input which means
`roll_dice` will always be equal to **yes** and you will be stuck in an infinite loop.

You should use:

```
roll_dice = input(prompt)
```

which sets `roll_dice` to the new value, and hence lets you exit out of the loop.

Comment: thank you! I can't believe it was that simple of a fix. I'm having trouble with while loops, but I will get better. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Stanimal If my answer helped you, please consider marking this question as helpful (the up arrow) and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code in this manner:

```
while roll_dice =="yes":
      print ("you rolled", random.randint(min, max), random.randint(min, max))
      roll_dice = input(prompt)
```

You must include roll_dice for getting the return value from the input function and validating if the response is yes, no or invalid.

In your code, input returns a value but that value is never checked after the if statement is executed once.

```
while roll_dice =="yes":
      print ("you rolled", random.randint(min, max), random.randint(min, max))
      input(prompt)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I can't believe it was that simple of a fix. I'm having trouble with while loops, but I will get better. Appreciate it!

Comment: Keep up the good work! You'll keep on getting better with time and effort! :)